# Wrong display date on all documents in my sharepoint document library

Tags: document-library

After changing the content type in my SharePoint document library, date of all the documents in my document library changes to January 2 1980. How do I revert this? I have changed the content type back to default, still not working.. Please help!

Comment: What date column are you referring to?  Is it a system column, e.g.: Created or Modified Date, or is it a custom date column?

Comment: Also, how did you change the content type on all the documents?

Comment: Yes, it is the Modified date that shows Jan 2 1980, also I cannot find the created date. I created a new content type in my document library and it changed the date for every document in the library.